# c# - Share class between Winform and aspx application

Tags: c#, .net, linux, winforms, mono

I've created a system formed bye a c#/winform application and c#/ASPX application who exchange information via XML files.

The c#/Winform application work as a frontend : make different operation and use some file saved as Xml to share information with other application.

The c#/ASPX application is my backend. I can call it by browser form other PC and through it I configure the front-end application.

The system works perfectly.

The question is this :
I've some classes that are the same in first and second application.
how can I use the classes, without having to rewrite them in a project and the other?

NOTE1 : I use visual studio express as IDE (visual express desktop 2015 for winform and visual express web 2015 for aspx)

NOTE2 : the application have to work on linux mono too.

Comment: Put your classes in a separate solution/project and reference it in both the other projects as a dll.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate class library project having the shared classes.  Then reference this class library from your WinForm and ASP.Net applications.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Also switch to Visual Studio Community Edition, so you can keep all your projects in single solution